# Erase a path in paper.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, paperjs

I basically want to create a new path with the canvas globalCompositeOperation set to 'destination-out'. Is this possible? If so, how?

I noticed that Item has a blendMode property: http://paperjs.org/reference/item#blendmode, but trying the different values does not provide the desired effect.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @EliteOctagon, what would you like the jsfiddle to contain?

Comment: Some of the working code. So as to play around with the path

Comment: @EliteOctagon, hopefully this will help: http://jsfiddle.net/D8vMG/6/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/D8vMG/12/

In light of your recent comment, you would need to create layers, as described here:

http://paperjs.org/tutorials/project-items/project-hierarchy/#removing-items-and-children

and then you can add your paths to a layer and do something like this:

```
 //add image to project as background
 // ... your code here ...

 var secondLayer = new Layer();
```

Whenever you create a new Layer, it becomes the active layer of the project, and then you can draw on top of the second layer all you want.

if you want a simple 'undo' button you can do:

```
 function onMouseDown(event) {
     if (window.mode == "drawing") {
        myPath = new Path();
        myPath.strokeColor = 'black';
     }
     else if (window.mode == "undo") {
        myPath.opacity = '0'; //this makes the last path used completely see through
        // or myPath.remove(); // this removes the path.
        //if you're intent on something that writes and erases, you could do 
     }
 }
```

But what you are looking for is something like this:

```
 function onMouseDrag(event) {
   if (window.mode == "drawing") {
     myPath.add(event.point);
   }
   else if (window.mode == "erasing") {
     myPath.removeSegment(0);
   }
 }
```

this erases the segments of the path from beginning to end. For the full functionality, you need something that identifies a path on click, (layer.getChildren() ? then select child). Then using the point on mouse move you need to identify the segment index and remove it from the path using .removeSegment(index).

http://paperjs.org/reference/path#removesegment-index

Comment: Still no cigar. :) I was able to implement it by using the low level canvas api for erasing paths and paper.js for everything else. What you have achieved simply erases "segments" from existing paths. What if there's text, rects, and other shapes? I need the ability to erase paths on top of shapes (like the erase tool in photoshop).

Comment: @TheOne: Im looking for a similar functionality where I can select an item - rectangle/point/circle and delete..How were you able to do it..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simple solution would be to just create a path which is white.  http://jsfiddle.net/D8vMG/11/

```
function onMouseDown(event) {
    if (window.mode == "drawing") {
       myPath = new Path();
       myPath.strokeColor = 'black';
     }
     else if (window.mode == "erasing") {
        myPath = new Path();
        myPath.strokeColor = 'white';
        myPath.strokeWidth =  10;
     }
}
```

Comment: this way the erasing is larger than the drawing.

Comment: Simple but useless :-) my use case has a background image.